# Prove $\operatorname*{res}_{z=z_0} f(z)g'(z) = - \operatorname*{res}_{z=z_0} f'(z)g(z) $

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> If $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z_0$ show that:
>
> $$\operatorname*{res}_{z=z_0} f(z)g'(z) = - \operatorname*{res}_{z=z_0} f'(z)g(z)$$

Here is my proof using partial integration:

#### Proof

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname*{res}_{z=z_0} f(z)g'(z) &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\partial B(z_0,r)} f(z)g'(z) \,\text{d}z \\
&\stackrel{\text{P.I.}}{=} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \left[ f(z)g(z)\right]^{z_1}_{z_0} - \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\partial B(z_0,r)} f'(z)g(z) \,\text{d}z\\
&= \color{red}{\frac{1}{2\pi i} \left[ f(z)g(z)\right]^{z_1}_{z_0}} - \operatorname*{res}_{z=z_0} f'(z)g(z)\\
&= \ldots
\end{align}$$

Which proves the theorem if $\color{red}{ \left[ f(z)g(z)\right]^{z_1}_{z_0} = 0}$, but why would that be the case?

Comment: What do we know about $g$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $z_0=z_1$, you shouldn't call the initial and final points of the curve like this since the center of the circle is $z_0$. To see it more clearly you may parametrize the curve.
\begin{align}
\operatorname*{res}_{z=z_0} f(z)g'(z) &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\partial B(z_0,r)} f(z)g'(z) \operatorname dz \\
&=  \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(z_0+re^{it})g'(z_0+re^{it})ire^{it} \operatorname{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(f(z_0+re^{it})g(z_0+re^{it})\left.\right\rvert_{0}^{2\pi} - \int_0^{2\pi}f'(z_0+re^{it})re^{it} g(z_0+re^{it})\operatorname dt \right)\\
&= 0 - \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\partial B(z_0,r)} f'(z)g(z) \operatorname dz\\
&= -\operatorname*{res}_{z=z_0} f'(z)g(z)
\end{align}

Comment: You have forgot a. the $z_0$ in the argument of all functions and b. to take into account the exponential function in the partial integration. One needs to evaluate $(f(z_0+re^{it})ire^{it})'$ with the product rule and gets an additional integral there which one has to consider.

Comment: You're right about a. But I think my integration is correct. The exponential appears because of the chain rule. Anyway I'll give a look and edit it asap.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively: Functions that have an anti-derivative on a small neighbourhood around $z_0$ have zero residue in $z_0$ and therefore $(f\cdot g)' = f'\cdot g + f\cdot g'$ implies $0=\operatorname{res}\limits_{z=z_0} (f'(z)g(z) + f(z)g'(z)) = \operatorname{res}\limits_{z=z_0} f'(z)g(z) + \operatorname{res}\limits_{z=z_0} f(z)g'(z)$.

Comment: why would the product have an antiderivative in a neighbourhood?

Comment: @hjhjhj57 Since $(f\dot g)'$ is explicitly a derivative, it has $f\dot g$ as an antiderivative.  As to the unasked question of why such a function has zero residue, one can either use a path integral formulation (where evaluating the integral will yield cancelation of the value of the antiderivative at the end point from the value at the starting point), or simply note that if we write a function as a Laurent series about $(z-a)$, there is no $\log (z-a)$ term to yield a $(z-a)^{-1}$ in the derivative.

Comment: @Aaron But if either $f$ or $g$ have a pole at $0$ then their product needn't be differentiable.

Comment: not at $z_0$, but that's not the point. They're holomoph in a pointed neighborhoud of $z_0$. That's the assumption here, otherwise the residuum isn't welldefined !